# Regex issues with url rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-core

I'm using RegEx in C#/ASPNET Core 2.0 for URL Rewriting. Basically I need to match this:

```
blocked\/([a-z]{1,3})\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/(.*)\/?
```

However, it's not working as expected. I need to match the following:

```
/blocked/en/test1/
/blocked/en/test1/test2/
/blocked/en/test1/test2
/blocked/en/
/blocked/eN/test1
```

match 1: en
match 2: test1
match 3: test2

If match 2 or 3 is missing, or just 3, I still want to match. So the following should be:

```
/blocked/en/test1/ - MATCH en, test1
/blocked/en/test1/test2/ - MATCH en, test1, test2
/blocked/en/test1/test2 - MATCH en, test1, test2
/blocked/en/ - MATCH en
/blocked/en/test1 - MATCH en, test1
```

I also need the trailing slash to be ignored. Basically any combination should match.

https://regex101.com/r/Bvm9yl/2/

Any suggestions, along with explanation, is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: What does "However, it's not working as expected." mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
(?<=\/blocked\/)([a-zA-Z]{1,3})\/(\w+)?\/?(\w+)?\/?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RRYvRw/1)

Expression Diagram:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I use regex on a daily basis before whatever reason I kept failing on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple in this case , It can be done in two steps :

Steps :

```
1. Extract the pattern using regex.
    pattern = "blocked\/.*"
2. Split the string based on "/" , and all take entries other than first i.e blocked
```

Hope this helps